# Retrieving values from json with getType using newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json

I love the way, how I can do this in `Java`. Simply with:

```
JSONObject obj = ...; // got by some procedure
String val_1 = obj.getString("attr_1");
int val_2 = obj.getInt("attr_2");
```

But I do not know whether there is something similar in `C#`. Doing type casting at every line of code is not something that I want. BTW. I'm using `newtonsoft.json`.

Comment: What is that you really want to achieve here ?

Comment: I want to retrieve values of particular data type.

Comment: You mean you wanna retrieve values from json string i.e values of a certain type ?

Comment: Exactly! That is what I want. And I do not want to type cast myself.

Comment: Just derserialize the JSON-Object into a proper type.

Comment: Just do JsonConvert.DeserializeObject on your string

Comment: If you want details i can post an answer

Comment: @Rinecamo. For a C#-newbie like me, it sounds like - "just do it". Can you, please, elaborate on this?

Comment: @ Kayani, you are welcome!

Comment: @ Kayani But, please, if you will use some method that needs `using blablabla;`, please, include that in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so in addition to @Kayani 's answer:
Let's assume you have the following json:

```
{  
  "AttributeOne":"TestString",
  "AttributeTwo":1000
}
```

The corresponding class in C# would be this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public String AttributeOne { get; set; }
    public Int32 AttributeTwo { get; set; }
}
```

So what you can do now is this:

```
TestClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(str); //str = your json
String val_1 = obj.AttributeOne; //String
Int32 val_2 = obj.AttributeTwo; //Int
```

So you don't have to cast in every line.
If that still doesn't solve your problem, you could write some extensions like this:

```
public static class JObjectExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this JObject obj, string property)
    {
        return obj[property].ToString();
    }

    public static int GetInt(this JObject obj, string property)
    {
        return (int)obj[property];
    }
}
```

And use them like this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(str); //str == your json
String val_1 = obj.GetString("attr_1");
int val_2 = obj.GetInt("attr_2");
//or you just use the built in methods
String val_1 = obj.Value<String>("AttributeOne");
int val_2 = obj.Value<int>("AttributeTwo");
```

For these snippets you need to import (using) `Newtonsoft.Json` and `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a json string like the following:

```
{"question":"what is your name","A":"x","B":"y","C":"z","D":"a"}
```

Here we have a MCQ type question in the json string. Say we want to retrieve one of its property such as question. What we will do is that we create a class with the following properties:
question,A,B,C,D. Lets say the class is named `MyQuestion` we will just do the following:

```
MyQuestion myQuestion = JsonConvert.DerserializeObject<MyQuestion>(jsonString);
```

now you can access any property of the myQuestion object.
Ref: [JsonConvert](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)

Comment: Thanks! I find that useful. Although, it is not exactly what I want. I was talking about getting values of a particular data type from a json object. Say, I know that "question" property (from your example) is a string, then I will do something like `string var_1 = jsonobj.GetString("question");`

Comment: @Jacobian But why do you want to do it this way when there is a much easier one?

Comment: @Rinecamo. Again, you are saying that there is an easier method, but do not show it. Would you be so kind to put all cards on the table?

Comment: @Rinecamo. If you make a better answer, I will re-accept it.

Comment: @Rinecamo as per my understanding of the problem this was the requirement. If you have a better alternative no one is stopping you to come up with one

Comment: @Kayani Your code is pretty much what I have in my mind, although I have the feeling Jacobian doesn't really understand how it can be used.

Comment: @Rinecamo  "I have the feeling Jacobian doesn't really understand how it can be used" - exactly. Otherwise, I would not ask this question